# Validation rules to allow at most 10 user registration for same phone number in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

In a system, what should be the validation rules to allow at most 10 users to register with same phone number?

From googling, Laravel documentation and Laracast didn't find anything.

May be there is nothing like that. So I decided to set a check in registration controller like -

- count number of phone numbers in users table
- check if quota is finished already.
- register or discard

This should do my job. But is there any way to do the check in validation rule?

P.S. For authentication I am using the shipped `Auth` with the framework and Laravel 5.2.

Comment: I am not a Laravel guy but there must be some callback system while setting the validation rules so you can use that.

Comment: @Muhammad, laravel has it's way of validation by default. You just need to pass the `rules`. Here I am seeking the `rule` that should be pass to achieve my goal.

Comment: you know there are no rules for all kind of validations, if you see the list of rules its limited but its flexible you can create your own rules. See this link https://laravel-news.com/custom-validation-rule-objects

Answer (score 0):

My quick suggestion will be to wrap the 'return true'; from your Request file statement in the logic for your situation.

public function authorize () 
{

```
  if (something) {
       return true;
   }
```

}

Hope it helps or at least give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can run query to get the user with same phone number.

```
$phone_no = Input::get('phone_number');

$user_phone_no = DB::table('users')->where('phone_number',$phone_no)->get();

$count = count($user_phone_no);

if($count < 10)
 {return true;}

else
 {return false};
```

Comment: Please read the question before answering. 
I have described this as I can do the job like this. But I am searching something by default like `max:10` for string length validation.